# Textarea with dynamic width next to a submit button

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea on the left side which should use around 80 % of the screen and a button next to the textarea on the right side.

When the browser window gets smaller, the textarea should get smaller and the button should stay on the right side next to the textarea.

Unluckily my code stops working when the window gets too small.

The text-overflow is not working too.

Any ideas?

Thx!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        body, #content { width: 100%; }
        textarea { width: 80%; }
        button {
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            display: block;
            overflow: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <textarea rows="10">x</textarea>
            <input value="Submit Something" class="button" id="submitSomething" name="submitSomething" type="submit">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/0ospfv4r/

Comment: Please write it as answer, so that I can accept it :)

Comment: There I've added it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        float: right;
        right: 0;
        position: fixed;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `calc` to calculate the remaining width and assign it to your textarea.

You fix your button width in pixels e.g. `width: 120px;` and the specify `width: calc(100% - 120px);` to your textarea.

***Example***:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
html, body { }
body, #content { width: 100%; }
textarea { width: calc(100% - 140px); }
.button {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <textarea rows="10">x</textarea>
    <input value="Submit Something" class="button" id="submitSomething" name="submitSomething" type="submit">
</div>
```

*Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/0ospfv4r/*

If you notice in the example above, `140px` is used arbitrarily instead of `120px`. This is because, your element is set to `display: inline-block` and such elements take into account the white-space. So a width little larger than that is used.

You can get rid of the white-space by way of...

either this (*coalesce textarea and button together*):

```
<textarea rows="10">x</textarea><input value="Submit Something" class="button" id="submitSomething" name="submitSomething" type="submit">
```

or this (*close your textarea just before starting the button*):

```
<textarea rows="10">x</textarea
><input value="Submit Something" class="button" id="submitSomething" name="submitSomething" type="submit">
```

Then you can safely use `width: calc(100% - 120px)` on your textarea.